# cURL: (7) Failed to connect; Connection refused on Openstack Swift

Tags: curl, centos, openstack, openstack-swift

I'm trying to set up a 'Swift All In One' system on a CentOS 7 VM but when I run the command:

```
curl -v -H 'X-Storage-User: test:tester' -H 'X-Storage-Pass testing' http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/v1.0
```

I get the following error message:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080; Connection refused
```

Any ideas on what is causing this? I have added port 8080 to my IP table

Comment: I have not worked with Openstack. But as noone else answers, here are just some common ideas. I'm a bit confused about your ip adress `127/0/0/1`. I would use `127.0.0.1`. Did your Swift system listen on localhost (loopback device) or on a configured ip address e.g. `192.168....` (eth0 or whatever)? Did you open port 8080 on localhost or on the ip address associated with e.g. the eth0 device? You connect to an `auth` address, did yo provide the needed authentication data. (e.g. ssl keys or username/password)?

Answer (score 0):

**possible solution-1:**
you should execute your command on the SAIO machine where your swift is running  on. May be you are executing curl command on your host machine or somewhere else. make sure that you are on the correct terminal which is on SAIO machine.

**possible solution-2:**
may be your swift is not running on. you should use the following command: `swift-init all restart`

try these solutions, and inform me. so, May be, I can help you.